# Writing a security suite

Tags: java, javascript, asp.net, c++

Is there a way that I can integrate a pattern, say for a song tempo, into being used for access into a system?
To give more detail, if I wanted to discourage hackers from gaining access, is there a way that I can make a suite that would search the persons system covertly for a MAC address and ban that address if he/she doesn't get a certain tempo right with the keystrokes?

Comment: I would recommend a DNA sequence scan as a security feature. Hackers will have hard time breaking DNA sequence. People can use DNA of their pets, if they are concerned about privacy.

Comment: DNA sequencing seems more like an "on-site" feature, I'm looking to make something that is more akin to a program like Norton or Kaspersky.

Comment: So you are trying to discourage deaf and hard-of-hearing hackers from gaining access to your system?

Comment: @JustinMuller That seems like an outrageous discrimination to me. Can those hackers, possibly, file a lawsuit? I wonder...

Comment: Apparently I need to reword the question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems pretty straightforward. You make an element that times keystrokes, you send the raw timing data back to the server, analyze it there against known patterns and what the tolerance of error is.

While it seems a bit wonky and perhaps not exactly user friendly (there's only a limited number of combinations of tempos and strokes so it would get cracked quickly) the digital logistics of it are pretty easy if you break it down into a handful of simple components.

Comment: Okay, what if I had a songlist with thousands of songs that cycled randomly by the hour? This isn't meant for a site log in or anything like that, it's going to be used more in a sense of admin privileges to a server, a way to stop a hacker from accessing any part of a site's underlying code or a servers stored data. Maybe even a way to keep any intrusion from being undetectable and quickly eliminate that signature from the network?

Comment: Well all of that will work. You just send the sample of the song to the client, the user has to enter the proper beat with the keyboard or mouse, you time the inputs and send the results back for analysis. I still think this will be less effective than just having a good permission system. There's plenty of resources on authorization and authentication if you're having trouble with it, and this scheme, while fun to implement, isn't something I'd recommend for a serious commitment. Too... error prone? Kind of reinventing a wheel that's already pretty round.